# Azure app performance

Tags: c#, .net, azure

I am completely new to the Azure and cloud overall and I have been asked this question:

> Imagine you are managing a web application hosted in Azure with a large user base in United States and Europe.
>   In order to improve performance and user experience you want to host 2 instances of the same application one for US based users and one for Europe based users.
>   Can you briefly explain how would you accomplish this with Azure services?

We cannot use two links

```
Http://myapp-us
Http://myapp-eu
```

We have only one url;

```
Http://myapp
```

Therefore we just cannot deploy two instances in eu region server, and american region server. Is there any way to improve performance without that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would use the [Azure Traffic Manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/traffic-manager/traffic-manager-overview) to control the distribution for user traffic. It directs client traffic to the appropriate instance of your app based on the proximity of the request and the health of the available instances.
Some useful links

- [Traffic Manager overview](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/traffic-manager/)
- You would need to use the [Geographic routing method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/traffic-manager/traffic-manager-configure-geographic-routing-method) to route traffic to specific endpoints based on the request location.
- A [good description](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/traffic-manager/traffic-manager-routing-methods#geographic) of how the Geographic traffic routing works.